# Are Linux commands interchangeable with Unix commands?

Tags: linux, unix

I find that some commands, for example, `ls` and `pwd`, can be used on both Linux and Unix systems.

- Is it that all Linux commands can be used in the Unix systems, and all Unix commands can be used in Linux?
- Or just that all the Linux commands can run on Unix but not all Unix commands can run on Linux.
- Or that all Unix commands can run on Linux, but not all Linux commands can run on Unix?
- Or is there a reference to show me which commands can run on both Linux and Unix, and where both have their own unique command?

Comment: Read about "POSIX".

Comment: Note that it's not a "Linux" command, it's a GNU command. The GNU tools can be installed on FreeBSD, for example.

Comment: Heck, the GNU tools can even be installed on Unix.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Daniel Andersson's comment about POSIX is the real answer here: there is a standard called POSIX which defines the core of a UNIX-like system, both in terms of shell commands and system calls. In theory, if you write software to the POSIX spec, it should be possible to compile and run it on any UNIX, Linux, BSD etc system.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/mindex.html will give you a *definitive* answer as to what constitutes POSIX, but that's not a useful answer for practical purposes. Someone else may have good command references for common differences between Linux systems and other UNIX-like systems.

One specific example: "killall" on Linux kills all processes with a particular name. On Solaris, it shuts the system down. Important not to use the wrong one.

Comment: Linux ***is*** Unix, you know.

Comment: @tchrist- if you really think that, type "sudo apt-get" on Mac OS X and see how far it gets you.

Comment: @tchrist when Ted Wong mentioned Linux he was obviously talking about the operating system that is also know as GNU/Linux and it says right there in the name that ["GNU's Not Unix!"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) ;)

Comment: Actually, as I understand it, Mac OS X IS a certified Unix--something very few (if any) of the Linux variants achieved.  Obviously this would be just a matter of certification to a very basic standard.

Comment: AFAIK Unix systems inherited the code from some branch of AT&T's original UNIX. Linux was a fresh start from scratch to exploit the new multitasking features of Intel's 80386 processor. I recommend to read "Just for fun" from Linus Torvalds.

Comment: @tchrist **L** inux **I** s **N** ot **U** ni **X**

Comment: @Dave Bah.  Don’t be lame.  Call a spade a spade, a `cat` a `cat`, and remember that a rose by any other name shall still smell as sweet.  Hie thee to a Windows box and learn what Unix is ***not***.  But Linux is of course Unix.

Comment: @tchrist GNU `cat` is just a symlink to `viscous-mountain-lion`

Answer (score 18):

Most Linux distributions today come with lots of essential GNU software and the GNU Toolchain. GNU was a project to rewrite a free-as-in-freedom copy of Unix that later got paired together with the Linux kernel. When you use `ls` on a Unix machine you're using the original/what's become of the original `ls`. When you use `ls` on GNU/Linux, you're using the GNU `ls` which was written from scratch to be the same as `ls`. However, not all GNU software is exactly the same as its Unix counterparts. Now that Unix has essentially turned into BSD, GNU/Linux distros may also contain the BSD version of that tool. For example, `bsdtar` and `tar` come to mind.

tl;dr: They aren't the exact same code, but they are meant to for the most part be exactly the same.

Comment: As for differences the `ps` is the most annoying example I can think of. Different switches on different systems (Linux, AIX and Solaris). Also different format of output. Though the purpose of that command is the same on all systems.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify which UNIX you're talking about (BSD, System V...). There's no universal (UNIX) answer. Each UNIX variant has its own custom commands (take Mac OS X for example), so even between UNIXes there are different commands. Usually old commands (like ls, pwd, cd, cp, mv, rm...) tend to be the same on all UNIX flavors (including Linux).

Comment: [officially trademarked as UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix)

Answer (score 4):

What you need to consider first is that the commands are actually small programs, in that sense not necessarily a part of the operating system if you split hairs. The old and classic ones have been around for a long time, and are included in most *nix systems. Just how "complete" the OS is depends on what comes with the package.

As an example most recovery/emergency CDs you can boot from contain a slim Linux distro, you would find that some typical commands might not be featured in these systems, purely because they would not be needed in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

On solaris you just have to add `/usr/gnu/bin` to your path or exchange it with `/usr/bin` and your command sets will be very similar